# Should I remove a variable from a PCA analysis if it is the only variable to load on a component?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, factor-analysis

I have four continuous variables drawn from secondary data of companies. The combination of these four variable represent my dependent variable. These four variables are real values. They are just only four values with no items. I am using PCA to combine them together. The results I have got are that three variables are categorized under one component and fourth is categoarized alone under the second component.

**Should I consider these two componenents as two dependent variables, one with three variables and the second one with one variable or should I just delete the second component?**

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

In simplified terms, you have three variables measuring one thing, and a fourth variable measuring something else. You need to determine **what is this something else? And is it something that you are interested in measuring?**

In some cases, a single variable unrelated to the other variables might be considered to be uninteresting. E.g., a poorly worded question or a variable that mainly reflects noise.

In other cases, such a variable may be your only measure recorded on an additional facet of what you were interested. e.g., imagine you had three variables measuring financial performance and one measuring corporate governance; even if the corporate governance variable didn't load on the same component as the financial performance variables, it is still an interesting variable.